# Conversion failed when converting varchar value to data type int error in Visualstudio

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, type-conversion, varchar

Query:

```
SELECT CAST(College_Year AS VARCHAR(10)),
       Learner_Id,
       Forename_1,
       Surname,
       sum(Possible_Duration) AS Possible_Duration,
       sum(Present_Duration) AS Present_Duration,
       CASE
           WHEN sum(Present_Duration) = 0 THEN 0
           ELSE sum(Present_Duration) / sum(Possible_Duration)
       END AS Attendance
FROM dbo.IM_AT_Attendance_vw
WHERE Session_date >=
    (SELECT ACYR_Start_Date
     FROM dbo.ACYR
     WHERE dbo.IM_fnCurrentACYR() = ACYR_College_year)
  AND Session_Date <=
    (SELECT ACYR_End_Date
     FROM dbo.ACYR
     WHERE dbo.IM_fnCurrentACYR() = ACYR_College_year)
  AND Session_Date NOT IN
    (SELECT Holiday_Date
     FROM IM_EFC_Holidays)
  AND Possible = 1
  AND month(Session_Date) = month(DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE()))
  AND Learner_ID = @Learner_ID
GROUP BY College_Year,
         Learner_Id,
         Forename_1,
         Surname
ORDER BY Surname,
         Attendance
```

above query works fine in SSMS but when I execute from visual studio throws an error:

> Conversion failed when converting varchar value '414084H' to datatype int.

I am guessing problem with LearnerID column - datatype varchar(12)

I tried CAST(Learner_ID AS INT) and CONVERT(INT, Learner_ID) but doesn't help....

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Ar

Comment: Please add more context to your question

Comment: @blackbishop - please see above

Answer (score 1):

Your LearnerID value "414084H" contains a letter at the end. Therefore it cannot be converted to integer.

If the format is alyways the same you can select just the first 6 characters from your value in the select, and this way the conversion will succeed:

```
select SUBSTRING(LearnerID, 0, 6)
```

Comment: You can try to cast the string to int directly in the stored procedure. So: SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(LearnerID, 0, 7) AS INTEGER). I just noticed you have to send as a parameter 7, not 6, to take all the digits into consideration.

Comment: Error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '4B0446' to data type int.

Comment: I tried CAST(Learner_ID AS INT) and CONVERT(INT, Learner_ID) but doesn't help....

Comment: Of course it does not work, the value "4B0446" does not have the same format as the other value "414084H", so you cannot use the formula to generalize. You should think about why you need to convert this value to an integer because obviously it is not an integer. It is a string. Therefore you should modify the variable type in your c# code.

Comment: I have changed LearnerID parameter datatype to text from integer but I cannot get rid of the error :(

Comment: It is impossible you have the same error because both values are now strings, therefore no "Error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value  to data type int. " could emerge. Can you add the exact error that you are receiving now and also the code sample in c# that calls the stored procedure ?

Comment: An error occurred while reading data from the query result set. Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '436603J' to datat type int. (Error: 245)

Comment: select CAST([College_Year] as Varchar(10))
,Learner_ID]
  FROM dbo.IM_AT_Attendance_vw where 
learner_ID = @learner_ID     order by college_year desc

Comment: You still did not change the date type in the c# code. You are still trying to convert the string to int. That's why I asked for the C# CODE, nor for the sql select script.

Comment: Oh, with that I cannot help you. You have to demand the person who implemented it.

Comment: I'm sure you can find someone that has access to your application. It can be any programmer who does, not necessarily the person who wrote that specific report. There is nothing you can do from sql, it is indeed a change who needs to be done in the c# code, as obviously this field is a string, not an int.